# Learning problem during training pretrained CNN for multilabel image classification

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, multilabel-classification

I'm trying to train a CNN to classify images with 3 classes. Each image can belong to several classes. So in network output I expect a probability for each class.

When I do the data loading I have a pandas dataframe with columns:[imageID, class 1, class 2, class 3]. Images size are (256,256,3) and label is (3,1) (ex: if an image belongs to class 1 and class 2 label is [1,1,0])

Then, here is my model:

```
print("Define model")
base_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(256,256,3),weights='imagenet')
base_model.trainable = True
fine_tune_at = 15

for layer in base_model.layers[:fine_tune_at]:
    layer.trainable =  False


global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(256,256,3))
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)

x = global_average_layer(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
outputs = prediction_layer(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)


base_learning_rate = 0.00001
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=base_learning_rate),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False), #True
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print("Training")
history = model.fit(train_generator, epochs = 75, validation_data= val_generator)
```

But my model doesn't learn anything, there is a problem and I don't know how to solve it.
Here is the training curve : [image: training curve]

Comment: shouldn't training=False be True instead?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy
Use this cross-entropy loss when there are **only two label classes** (assumed to be 0 and 1). For each example, there should be a single floating-point value per prediction.

```
y_true = [[0., 1.], [0., 0.]]
y_pred = [[0.6, 0.4], [0.4, 0.6]]
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy
Use this crossentropy loss function when there are **two or more label classes**. We expect labels to be provided in a one_hot representation. If you want to provide labels as integers, please use SparseCategoricalCrossentropy loss. There should be # classes floating point values per feature.

```
y_true = [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
y_pred = [[0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]]
```

Comment: OP says **multilabel** classification, so the network setup with BinaryCrossentropy seems correct for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. However my model still doesn't learn..

Comment: @Leili_Kue Is your dataset balanced? if not, maybe you could consider some kind of FocalLoss

Comment: Also... maybe this would help https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/losses/npairs_multilabel_loss